# PHP form and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a PHP form that adds data to a MySQL DB, I now have to convert that PHP code so that it will work on a MSSQL DB. PHP is running fine on the server.

Here's what I have so far, basically I changed everything that WAS mysql_ to mssql_ but it's not working. I have a line that I'm not showing that calls a config file that connects to the DB as well, I'm also not showing the HTML form unless you need it.

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['vendor_id'])) { //Check for a field that is mandatory to do the inserted
        $vendor = mssql_escape_string($_POST['vendor_id']);
        $name = mssql_escape_string($_POST['name_id']);
        $version = mssql_escape_string($_POST['version']);
        $serial = (!empty($_POST['serial'])) ? $_POST['serial'] : 'NULL';
        $productkey = (!empty($_POST['productkey'])) ? $_POST['productkey'] : 'NULL';
        $department = mssql_escape_string($_POST['department']);
        $owner = mssql_escape_string($_POST['owner']);
        $computer = (!empty($_POST['computer'])) ? $_POST['computer'] : 'NULL';
        $comments = (!empty($_POST['comments'])) ? $_POST['comments'] : 'NULL';
        $acquired = (!empty($_POST['acquired'])) ? $_POST['acquired'] : 'NULL';
        $retired = mssql_escape_string($_POST['retired']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.keylist_detail (vendor_id,name_id,version,Serial,ProductKey,department_ID,owner,computer,Comments,acquired,retired)
            VALUES (''$vendor','$name','$version',$serial','$productkey','$department','$owner','$computer','$comments','$acquired','$retired'')";
    mssql_query($SQL);
    if (mssql_query($sql)) {
        echo '<strong><em>Your data has been submitted</em></strong><br /><br />';
            } else {
        echo '<p>Error adding submitted info: ' . mssql_error(). '</p>';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use `PDO` instead, much easier when changing database drivers/types.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't know much about MSSQL.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error log? FYI your question will be bumped up if you edit the question with more information. Please edit with errors from your error log.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have too many `'`. Here:

```
''$vendor'
```

and here:

```
'$retired''
```

Comment: I took out the extra quotes and I have the same problem.

Comment: Bumping my question.. Thanks!